# The script stops working after compilation

Tags: exe

I made a small script that should look for an icon (photo.png), then if he sees it, he should click the left mouse button. When you run an uncompiled project, everything works. As soon as I compile it, the command line opens and then closes. Here is the code:

```
from python_imagesearch.imagesearch import imagesearch
import pyautogui
import keyboard

while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                break
        else:
                circle = imagesearch("photo.png")
                if circle[0] != -1:
                        pyautogui.click()
```

When the program starts, the console starts, the program searches for the icon and then clicks on the left mouse button. I tried to change libraries, but nothing helps.

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?